# Android Things: How to calibrate touch screen

Tags: touch, android-things

How can I calibrate touch screen on Android Things running or Raspberry Pi 3?

I have a 10" LCD display with touchscreen.  It works, but it registers touches in wrong spots.  To fix it I would need to scale the X,Y coordinates down by about 20% and apply an offset of about 10mm.  Is there a why to do it on Android Things?

Comment: Please add more details about your touch screen (at least model).

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko There is no model. It's a while label screen from AliExpress: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Waveshare-10-1inch-HDMI-LCD-B-with-case-IPS-Touch-Screen-1280x800-high-resolution-Supports-Multi/32679570723.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.iTtvRo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Modify the Android framework
2. Modify linux driver
3. Update firmware if the controller supports

I'm used to the 2nd method. 
When booting the Android reads properties from kernel, such as abs-x, abs-y. The typical resolution of the touch controller is 4096. ie, the contoller returns 0~4095. So your panel reduces 20%, ranges 0 to 4096*0.8 ≈ 3277. 10mm offset in 10inch equals how many pixels? for example 200, then min-x is 200, max-x is 3477.

In the probe function of linux driver, call

```
input_set_abs_params(input_dev, ABS_X, min-x, max-x, 0, 0);
input_set_abs_params(input_dev, ABS_Y, min-y, max-y, 0, 0);
```